Input Data From Excel to Posthog
I want to create a display of the user install data plan in my application. Therefore, I need external data that contains all the users in my company, so I can find out who has installed the application and who hasn't installed it. The data is available in my excel, how do I input the data, is it possible?
So that Excel data in CSV form can be entered into Posthog
